# Read Log files in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want capture the changed data in Cosmos DB(JSON document) using a schedule job via azure function or other way without impacting the online performance of the DB as web app/ Mobile App are reading and writing the data into Cosmos DB using API call. I want the data for offline ETL and analytical purpose the way oracle provides redo log files offline.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can probably use the [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the CosmosDB change events, you should use the [Cosmos Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed). Some sample use cases:

- Trigger an action when an item is inserted or updated
- Real-time stream processing
- Additional data movement for synchronization

Currently, my team is using an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions) with the [Cosmos DB Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2) to capture the change feed events in real-time.

**To answer your concern on affecting core operations from your application,** you might need to increase your throughput to handle the additional requests to process the change feed (aka, the request charge (aka RUs) / throughput).*CosmosDB is designed with elastic scalability of throughput* so as long as you allocate enough for your core operations + change feed you will be fine.  You can use the [Azure Portal Cosmos DB Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics) to see how much throughput you need to allocate. Also, you can log telemetry on each operation to monitor [request charge via the Cosmos SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/optimize-cost-queries#evaluate-request-unit-charge-for-a-query) or response header from the Cosmos DB Request. Cosmos will respond with the RUs in the following Http Response Header: *x-ms-total-request-charge*

**Monitor Request Charge Sample Code using the Cosmos SDK:**

```
// Measure the performance (request units) of writes 
ResourceResponse<Document> response = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionSelfLink, myDocument); 

Console.WriteLine("Insert of an item consumed {0} request units", response.RequestCharge); 

// Measure the performance (request units) of queries 
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionSelfLink, queryString).AsDocumentQuery(); 

while (queryable.HasMoreResults) 
{ 
          FeedResponse<dynamic> queryResponse = await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>(); 
          Console.WriteLine("Query batch consumed {0} request units", queryResponse.RequestCharge); 
}
```

**Monitor Request Sample Code using the Gremlin Driver:**

```
var client = await gremlinClient.Value.ConfigureAwait(false);
var result = await client.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(query, parameters)
                                              .ConfigureAwait(false);

bool hasRequestUnitsHeader = result.StatusAttributes.TryGetValue("x-ms-total-request-charge", out var requestUnits);
if (hasRequestUnitsHeader && double.TryParse(requestUnits.ToString(), out double requestUnitsAsDouble))
{
    appInsightsProvider.LogMetric("total-request-charge", requestUnitsAsDouble);
}
```

**Log Files**

I am not aware of another way to read data from Cosmos without allocating and consuming throughout via RUs. There are [log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk) for troubleshooting and diagnostics.

**Cosmos DB is designed to scale:**

> Cosmos DB enables you to elastically and independently scale throughput and storage across any number of Azure regions worldwide. You can elastically scale throughput and storage, and take advantage of fast, single-digit-millisecond data access using your favorite API including SQL, MongoDB, Cassandra, Tables, or Gremlin. Cosmos DB provides comprehensive service level agreements (SLAs) for throughput, latency, availability, and consistency guarantees, something no other database service offers.
>
> Elastic scalability of throughput and storage, worldwide Designed with
>   transparent horizontal partitioning and multi-master replication,
>   Cosmos DB offers unprecedented elastic scalability for your writes and
>   reads, all around the globe. You can elastically scale up from
>   thousands to hundreds of millions of requests/sec around the globe,
>   with a single API call and pay only for the throughput (and storage)
>   you need. This capability helps you to deal with unexpected spikes in
>   your workloads without having to over-provision for the peak. For more
>   information, see partitioning in Cosmos DB, provisioned throughput on
>   containers and databases, and scaling provisioned throughput globally.

Comment: Thanks Brennan for your answer. This is really helpful.

Comment: @user2941026  Happy to respond! If you think my response was helpful and it helped resolve your question, please participate in the stack overflow process by selecting an accepted answer :)